# What is a "high-pressure business"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

What is a "high-pressure business"?

I suppose it is a business in which people are often under high pressure, or a highly competitive business, but I still wanted to check here.

I came across it in a dialogue from a crime series:

> Lee works in a high-pressure business with lots of money at stake.
>   The phone could go any minute, telling him he had to be on a plane
>   the other side of the world on some multimillion deal.
>   There were things he couldn't tell me about who he met, where he was going.
>   He had security reviews three or four times a year. He didn't have a laptop
>   in case he put sensitive information on it and it was stolen.
>   Things like that.

Since Lee was murdered, and from the paragraph above, it is obvious that
Lee's job was risky and dangerous. I was wondering whether, in general
and not necessary in the context of previous paragraph, expression "high-pressure business" has some other connotation.

**LATER EDIT:** My dictionary gives, among others, these two meanings

> high-pressure (adj.) fig.: Urgent; intense; as, a high-pressure business or social life
>
> high-pressure (adj.) Using intense psychological pressure or other incentives to convince others to do things; aggressively persistent; as, high-pressure salesmen; high-pressure tactics.

In paragraph above, does "high-pressure business" refers to urgent, intense nature of the business (a phone could ring in the middle of the night, and in the next moment person is in the plane flying to the other side of the world to make a business deal), or high-pressure tactics used in the business that in the end escalated to Lee's murder? Or is it actually ambiguous?

Comment: I suppose it could be either of those, also, depending on the context. However, you didn't provide any context, so I don't think there's any way to say what it means for sure. I don't think it's a standard idiom or phrase with only one meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It could be either of those. If a business is in a highly competitive environment then the people in the business are likely to be often under a lot of pressure.

Quick googling shows most links for "high pressure business" actually are for companies offering pressure washing. It also suggests that "High pressure business practices" is more common than "a high pressure business".

This indicates that "High pressure business" is not a standard idiom and so it should be understood using the normal meaning of the words.

Comment: Searching the Internet, I got an impression that it is a standard idiom, but now I see that most of the hits were expression like "high-pressure business situation", "high-pressure business cycle", etc... But I did find one instance of expression "high-pressure business" in book [My Ladder of Life by Alan Duffy](https://books.google.rs/books?id=i6C1UDivq2oC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq="high-pressure+business"): "...At the time, the company's customers were a who's who of famous car makers. Price and delivery were crucial and it was a high-pressure business."